# What does this esoteric quote mean here?

Tags: grammar

> And he respects Owl, because you can't help respecting anybody who can spell TUESDAY, even if he doesn't spell it right; but spelling isn't everything. There are days when spelling Tuesday simply doesn't count.
>
> *The House at Pooh Corner*, A. A. Milne.

What does this quote mean?

Comment: I wonder why this quote is [esoteric](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/esoteric).

Comment: it is esoteric. The answer says it all!

Comment: You have no reason to take this out of context when asking your question.  Do not do so.  "And he respects Owl, because you can't help respecting anybody who can spell TUESDAY, even if he doesn't spell it right; but spelling isn't everything. There are days when spelling Tuesday simply doesn't count." - *The House at Pooh Corner*, A. A. Milne.

Comment: I've edited it to include the proper quote, but I've also VTC as you need to identify which part of the text is causing you the problem. Just proofreading the whole thing is off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

It is a reference to "Winnie the Pooh", a highly regarded children's book, by A. A. Milne.

Owl is the most learned creature in the Hundred Acre Wood, since he knows how to spell (although badly, he spells his own name WOL). He also doesn't know how to spell TUESDAY correctly, but since none of the other animals can either, and at least he can distinguish it from WEDNESDAY, this is thought to be quite an accomplishment.

(As an idiomatic expression it would equivalent to "one must respect someone who can do something you can't, even if they might do it badly").

Comment: So it is saying "any person who can spell Tuesday is worthy of respect. Thats why he respects Owl"

Comment: @user10395 Yes. Additionally, the construction *can't help* indicates that he is forced to respect Owl (or anyone else who can spell *Tuesday*), not that he merely chooses to.